# How to make a class work nicely with `hasattr` in `__getattr__` implementation?

Tags: python

I have a class, where `__getattr__` is implemented simply like:

```
    def __getattr__(self, item): return self.__dict__[item]
```

The problem I'm seeing is that many Python libraries (e.g. `numpy` and `pandas` are trying to sniff whether my object has something called `__array__` using this statement

```
hasattr(obj, '__array__`)
```

But my object is throwing an error at them saying there is no such attribute.

My dilemma: How can I make my class behave nicely with `hasattr` (by returning False) instead of throwing an error, WHILE at the same time, throw an error if any one wanted an attribute that doesn't exist (i.e. I still want that error to be thrown in any other case).

EDIT: reproducible code as requested:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, item): return self.__dict__[item]
a = A()
hasattr(a, "lol")
```

traceback:

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-b7d3ffac514f>", line 4, in <module>
    hasattr(a, "lol")
  File "<ipython-input-31-b7d3ffac514f>", line 2, in __getattr__
    def __getattr__(self, item): return self.__dict__[item]
KeyError: 'lol'
```

Comment: Can you include the traceback? `hasattr` is supposed to return False without throwing any error for attributes that aren't part of the object.

Comment: Its very simple traceback, it is one line that refers to the function you see at the top of the question. The dictionary is throwing it.

Comment: Done, please check the question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) ... should either return the attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception.

> [`hasattr(object, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) ... is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an `AttributeError` or not.

So you just need to raise an `AttributeError`:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        except KeyError:
            classname = type(self).__name__
            msg = f'{classname!r} object has no attribute {item!r}'
            raise AttributeError(msg)

a = A()
print(hasattr(a, "lol"))  # -> False
print(a.lol)  # -> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'lol'
```

(This error message is based on the one from `object().lol`.)

Comment: Ironicaly, I had that implemented years ago. But lately I was doing some cleansing and thought this code is superflous because the dictionary will take care of error throwing procedure. It caught me quickly.